# How can I Plot Phase Portraits Using ParametricNDSolve function(already know about StreamPlot function)?

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I have a 2nd order ODE:
$$\ddot{\phi}+3\dot{\phi}\sqrt{(\frac{8\pi G}{3})(\frac{1}{2}[\dot{\phi}^{2}+m^{2}\phi^{2}])}+\phi m^{2}=0.$$
I can use the StreamPlot command by breaking the ODE into a set of 2 first-order DEs.
But for my learning, I want to do it by using the parametricNDSolve command.
Here is what I tried, but the problem for me is $t$.

```
  eq=\[Phi]''[t]+3*\[Phi]'[t]*Sqrt[(8*Pi*G/3)*(0.5*\[Phi]'[t]^2+0.5*m^2*\[Phi][t]^2)]+\[Phi]*m^2==0  
  sol=ParametricNDSolve[{eq/.{G->1,m->0.5},\[Phi]'[0]=a,\[Phi]=b},{\[Phi],\[Phi]'},{t,0,1},{a,b}]
  ParametricPlot[Flatten[Table[\[Phi][a,b],\[Phi]'[a,b],{a,-1,1},{b,-1,1}],1]/.sol//Evaluate,{t,0,1}]
```

Comment: `NDSolve` is a purely numeric routine. Therefore, if you use `NDSolve` you need to give all parameters (such as G and m) some numeric values. Otherwise, it does not work.

Comment: see the second line of the code. I have provided the values of G and m.

Comment: I do not understand what do you try to obtain with the ParametricPlot. Maybe you should explain it better. Anyway, the code contains several errors. I corrected some and simplified the code: `sol = NDSolve[{\[Phi]''[t] + 
     3*\[Phi]'[t]*
      Sqrt[(8*Pi*1/3)*(0.5*\[Phi]'[t]^2 + 
          0.5*0.5^2*\[Phi][t]^2)] + \[Phi][t]*0.5^2 == 0, \[Phi][0] ==
     1, \[Phi]'[0] == 0}, \[Phi], {t, 0, 1}]
Plot[\[Phi][t] /. sol, {t, 0, 1}]` Like this it works, and can be a starting point for the folloing.

Comment: I want to plot $\dot{\phi}$ against $\phi$. I wanted to do it by using several initial conditions by using the parametricNDSolve command. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: ```sol = NDSolve[{\[Phi]''[t] + 
     3*\[Phi]'[t]*
      Sqrt[(8*Pi*1/3)*(0.5*\[Phi]'[t]^2 + 
          0.5*0.5^2*\[Phi][t]^2)] + \[Phi][t]*0.5^2 == 0, \[Phi][0] ==
     1, \[Phi]'[0] == 0}, \[Phi], {t, 0, 1}]
 ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{\[Phi]'[t], \[Phi][t]} /. sol, {t, 0, 1}]]```

Comment: This plot is for a single value of the initial condition. I want to do it for multiple initial conditions like a phase portrait.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here we have made some changes of your code.

```
eq = ϕ''[t] + 
    3*ϕ'[t]*
     Sqrt[(8*Pi*G/3)*(0.5*ϕ'[t]^2 + 
         0.5*m^2*ϕ[t]^2)] + ϕ[t]*m^2 == 0;
sol = ParametricNDSolve[{eq /. {G -> 1, m -> 0.5}, ϕ'[0] == 
     a, ϕ[0] == b}, {ϕ, ϕ'}, {t, 0, 1}, {a, b}];
ParametricPlot[
  Flatten[Table[{ϕ[a, b][t], ϕ'[a, b][t]}, {a, -1, 
       1, .25}, {b, -1, 1, .25}], 1] /. sol // Evaluate, {t, 0, 1}]
(* %/. 
 Line[a_] :> {Arrowheads[{{0.025, .85}}], Arrow[a]}*)
```

[image]

Comment: Can I remove arrows in it to get lines only? I tried it using Line-> True but it gave error.

Comment: @Jpmg Just remove the last line `/. 
 Line[a_] :> {Arrowheads[{{0.025, .85}}], Arrow[a]}`

Comment: I want these lines to be continuous trajectories. Plane lines properly rotating around the central part.

Comment: @Jpmg Maybe set `{t,0,10}` ?  `eq = ϕ''[t] + 
    3*ϕ'[t]*
     Sqrt[(8*Pi*G/3)*(0.5*ϕ'[t]^2 + 
         0.5*m^2*ϕ[t]^2)] + ϕ[t]*m^2 == 0;
sol = ParametricNDSolve[{eq /. {G -> 1, m -> 0.5}, ϕ'[0] == 
     a, ϕ[0] == b}, {ϕ, ϕ'}, {t, 0, 10}, {a, b}];
ParametricPlot[
 Flatten[Table[{ϕ[a, b][t], ϕ'[a, b][t]}, {a, -1, 
      1, .25}, {b, -1, 1, .25}], 1] /. sol // Evaluate, {t, 0, 10}, 
 AspectRatio -> 1]`

Comment: That worked awesomely. A many thanks and now the code is also understandable for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Manipulate[ Module[ {G = 1, t, tfinal = 1},
  eqn := {\[Phi]''[t] + 
      3*\[Phi]'[t]*
       Sqrt[(8*Pi*G/3)*(0.5*\[Phi]'[t]^2 + m^2*\[Phi][t]^2)] + \[Phi][
        t]*m^2 == 0, \[Phi][0] == IC1, \[Phi]'[0] == IC2};
  sol = First[NDSolve[eqn, \[Phi], {t, 0, tfinal}]];
  
  plot  = 
   ParametricPlot[
    Evaluate[{\[Phi]'[t], \[Phi][t]} /. sol, {t, 0, tfinal}]]
  
  ],
  "postion",
 {{IC1, 1, "\[Phi][0]"}, 0.5, 1.5, .1, Appearance -> "Labeled", 
  ImageSize -> Tiny},
 Delimiter, "velocity",
 {{IC2, 0, "\[Phi]'[0]"}, 0, 1, .1, Appearance -> "Labeled", 
  ImageSize -> Tiny},
 Delimiter, "mass",
 {{m, 0.5, "m"}, 0.1, 1, .1, Appearance -> "Labeled", 
  ImageSize -> Tiny},
 TrackedSymbols :> {IC1, IC2, m}, ControlPlacement -> Left]
```

Comment: Thanks for the code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sol = Table[
  NDSolve[{\[Phi]''[t] + 
      3*\[Phi]'[t]*
       Sqrt[(8*Pi*1/3)*(0.5*\[Phi]'[t]^2 + 
           0.5*0.5^2*\[Phi][t]^2)] + \[Phi][t]*0.5^2 == 
     0, \[Phi][0] == RandomReal[{-1, 1}], \[Phi]'[0] == 
     RandomReal[{-1, 1}]}, \[Phi], {t, 0, 1}], 50]; 

ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{\[Phi][t], \[Phi]'[t]} /. sol], {t, 0, 1}, 
  PlotRange -> All] /. Line -> Arrow
```

[image]

Have fun!

Comment: Thank you for the help.